# Filter records based on a combo box selection

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

OS - Win 10

Office 365

Hello,

I am attempting to create a form with a combo box to filter results.

I have one table that I want to filter. The filter is one of the columns in the table (using unique values from that column).

The following code returns a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error;

```
Sub SetFilter()

    Me.cboAcc.RowSource = "select * from frmQryLedger where ACCOUNT_ID = '" & Me.cboAcc & "'"

'For trouble shooting
    MsgBox Me.cboAcc.RowSource

End Sub

Private Sub cboAcc_AfterUpdate()

    'Call subroutine to set filter based on selected ACCOUNT_ID
    SetFilter

End Sub
```

Thank You

Ben

Comment: If Account_ID is number type, remove apostrophe delimiters which are only used for text type.

Comment: Thank You this was the problem.